# Page-responsive error with new react-app but the old one which are created in past are working fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, create-react-app

[that the image what is going on when i run the react file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iX9x.png)> this is my app.js file

> > I m trying to create an app every time I got a page unresponsive in my browser

```
    import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1>Hiii</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> this is the index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Can you give more information about the issue you are facing? Any logs or steps you did to build? Anything that might make this question a bit meaningful?

Comment: I just started the yarn start command on the terminal and it shows me these after running ones. Just npx create-react-app . command to create the file

Comment: anything in the logs?